# How does MEAT compare with RICE treatment to treat a tendinopathy (in terms of treatment efficiency)?

Tags: tendinopathy, treatment, physical-therapy

First, some acronym definitions:

- [RICE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RICE_(medicine)): Rest, Ice, Compression and Elevation.
- MEAT: movement, exercise, analgesia, treatment

How does MEAT compare with RICE treatment to treat a tendinopathy (specifically, a tendinosis)? I.e., which one leads to a better recovery? (I'm aware that better include several component such as how fast one recovers, how well, etc.)

I read [MEAT vs. RICE Treatment](https://web.archive.org/web/20130730131428/http://www.caringmedical.com:80/meat-vs-rice-treatment/) and [Steven Low's overcoming tendonitis](https://web.archive.org/web/20180323212120/http://stevenlow.org/overcoming-tendonitis/): they both advocate for MEAT without giving any scientific evidence MEAT is actually better than RICE.

Comment: Downvoter: please explain.

Comment: You may want to say what exactly do you mean with tendinopathy, because the term can refer to either acute tendon injury (tendinitis) or chronic injury (tendinosis).

Comment: @Jan good point, I meant tendinosis

Comment: What are the results of your research on pubmed?